# English/Spanish App: How do I set displayed values in spanish in values-es/strings but keep the values in English for the ifs checks in the app?

Tags: android, xml

I have the folder values with the strings.xml in English and values-es folder with another string.xml in spanish. I have a fragment that gets opened from the action bar to set the settings and store them in SharedPreferences, that works fine in English. I have a lot of if's in the app to check what is set on Share preferences but with the words in English and now in the strings.xml in spanish I want to do something like this to avoid changing all the ifs in the app. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 <string-array name="music">
        <item value="Yes">Si</item>
        <item value="No">No</item>
    </string-array>
```

Is there any way to do something similar? Basically I want the user to select "Si" on the preferences spinner but when I get the value from the spinner I want it to retrieve "Yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using constants for the value you need to save in shared preferences that way it will be language independent.

For example if you have 2 radio buttons for music naming on and off you should  create 2 constants

```
public static final int ON = 1;
public static final int OFF = 0;
```

Now on click of radio button you Should be checking id of radio button and saving appropriate constant in shared preferences:

```
case: R.id.radio_on 
//save ON in shared preferences 
break; 
case: R.id.radio_off 
    //save OFF in shared preferences
     break;
```

Then you can check for the constants independent of any language.

Comment: this did it...Thanks my friend

Answer (score 1):

Hi please pass the value si which you want to pass to string and take the value yes from your spinner just you can try this example 
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I want the user to select "Si" on the preferences spinner
>   but when I get the value from the spinner I want it to retrieve "Yes"

If you are displaying the values in Splanish and for particular part of code you want to retrieve the value in English below might be the way you are looking for.

```
Resources res = getResources();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
Locale savedLocale = conf.locale; // Save your current locale first (Splanish in your case)
conf.locale = new Locale("es"); // Change the desired locale( English in your case) 
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null); 

// retrieve resources from desired locale 
String str = res.getString(id);

// restore original locale 
conf.locale = savedLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);
```

I hope it will help.